# 60 words displayed only and database having 100 words

Tags: php, mysql

I only want the first 60 words of '$output' that has been uploaded 100 words to the database to be shown on my page, what is the simplest way for me to do this?

I want $output[]="description to only fetch first 60 words from the database.
** I have tried a lot method but  isn't working for me**

```
$output[]="<td>";
        $output[]="<img src='images/".$row_2[3]."' width=50 />";
        $output[]='</td>';
        $output[]='<td>';
        $output[]="Name:$row_2[1]<br>";
        $output[]="Price:$row_2[2]<br>";
        $output[]="Description:$row_2[5]<br>";
        $output[]="<a href=user.php?prdcod=$row_2[0]&usrcod=$usrcod>Add To Wishlist</a><br>";
        $output[]="<a href=purchase.php?prdcod=$row_2[0]&usercod=$usrcod&action=Add>Purchase</a>";
        $output[]='</td>';
```

Comment: How are you querying the database?

Comment: select * from tbprd where prdcatcod=$catcod and prdavlsts like'%Y%'

Comment: is there any other method to only use first 60 words like using substr

Comment: What is the Column name from which you nedd 60 Characters?

Comment: @Learner Are you doing this for `read more..` kind of a thing where you are going to use ellipsis(`.`) for users to click on `read more..` to see the full text?

Answer (score 2):

If your definition of a word is letters and/or numbers and other characters combined and separated with space then you can use explode to separate them, then slice out the first 60 and implode them back to string.

```
echo implode(" ", array_slice(explode(" ", $stringOf100Words), 0, 60));
```

See example here: https://3v4l.org/D4nqJ

If the string contains double spaces then you need to use preg_split, and split on any number of spaces with `"/\s+/"`.

```
implode(" ", array_slice(preg_split("/\s+/", $str), 0, 60));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but when i type 60 it goes 62 words but when i type 2 less than 60 it work for me.

Comment: That is strange. Is it the explode or the preg_split version you use? I think preg_split should be more accurate than explode since a double space can become a word with explode

Comment: what about word. It is fetching a 60 sentences

Answer (score 1):

The other answers don't respect interpunctuation or they count letters. Here is a small function:

```
function get60Words(string $str) {
    $words = str_word_count($str, 2);
    $cnt = 0;
    foreach($words as $strPos => $v) {
        if($cnt++ === 60) {
            return substr($str, 0, $strPos-1);
        }
    }

    return $str;
}
```

It gets the words of a string, gets the position of the 60th word and returns the substring.

Here a working example with 5 words: https://3v4l.org/N6J2R

Comment: Why is *count letters* important? Your output does not include dots and commas or any other non a-Z characters. Edit: sorry it does include the dots, my bad.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, I put it bad. I meant that one of the other answers does not count words but letters.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the MYSQL `SUBSTRING()` to extract 60 characters from your string. Considering your query, It should look something like this

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING(<COLUMN NAME>, 1, 60) AS ExractedString FROM tbprd WHERE prdcatcod='$catcod' AND prdavlsts LIKE '%Y%'
```

Replace `<COLUMN NAME>` with the column name from which you want to extract 60 characters

Comment: 60 words, not characters